# Server does not respond directly to my commands

Tags: java, netty

First of all, I'll admit I am new to this and I've probably just forgotten to set an option somewhere to the correct variable, but my Googling has failed me and I have no idea what to do, so I was hoping to get some help.

I have based this on the SecureChat example, it can be located here: http://netty.io/docs/unstable/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html

And the difference I have made, have been only in the SecureChatServerHandler. More precisely in the messageRecieved block:

```
@Override
public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) throws Exception {
    // Convert the message to a string
    String request = (String) e.getMessage();

    System.out.println("Message recieved: " + request);

    if (request.equalsIgnoreCase("clients")) {
        channels.write("We currently have: " + channels.size() + " clients");
    } else if (request.toLowerCase().equals("koko"))
        for (Channel c : channels) {
            if (c == e.getChannel())
                c.write("HELLO WORLD");
        }
    else {
        // Then send it to all channels, but the current one.
        for (Channel c : channels)
            if (c != e.getChannel())
                c.write("[" + e.getChannel().getRemoteAddress() + "] " + request + "\n");
            else
                c.write("[you] " + request + "\n");

    }

    if (request.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"))
        e.getChannel().close();
}
```

If I send a normal message that is getting broadcasted, everything works. But if I send a command, like **clients** or **koko**, I get no response, until I press enter again and send a empty message. First then I get the response back.

```
 C:\Device Manager\Application Server\Examp
 les\SecureChat\SecureChatClient\bin>java -jar client.jar 127.0.0.1 8080
 UNKNOWN SERVER CERTIFICATE: CN=securechat.example.netty.gleamynode.net, OU=Contr
 ibutors, O=The Netty Project, L=Seongnam-si, ST=Kyunggi-do, C=KR
 Welcome to Electus secure chat service!
 Your session is protected by TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA cipher suite
 You are the 1th user
 koko<ENTER>
 <PRESS ENTER AGAIN>
 HELLO WORLD[you]
 clients<ENTER>
 <AND ENTER ONCE AGAIN>
 We currently have: 1 clients[you]
```

What I don't understand, and don't want, is the -pressing of enter button twice- thing. It seems highly inlogical and it is irritating. I didn't have these problem with the Telnet Example.

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
Aldrian.

Comment: Did some testing, and without the if/else thing, it seems to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those humiliating times where you just forgot one small detail, and that messes everything up.

```
if (request.equalsIgnoreCase("clients")) {
    channels.write("We currently have: " + channels.size() + " clients /n"); // Forgot /n here
} else if (request.toLowerCase().equals("koko"))
    for (Channel c : channels) {
        if (c == e.getChannel())
            c.write("HELLO WORLD /n"); // <- Forgot /n here as well
    }
```